# Laravel Passport: Authenticate api requests based on access token issued by another microservice

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have 3 services. app.mydomain.com, accounts.mydomain.com and api.mydomain.com. The accounts.mydomain.com authenticates and issues the access token using passport. My question is to how can i use this access token issued by accounts service to allow access to the resources of api service.

Comment: Im also facing to same problem

Comment: let me know if you have any thing about this

Comment: mechanism for this is you have to save the passport key in local storage and then when each time the relevant user request a request key should be authenticated . This should be done in each function. I know how to retrive the key and then to store it into local storage but unfortunately still couldnt find the way to check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways:

1) Create an introspection endpoint on `account.mydomain.com` server to be called by `api.mydomain.com` to check access token.

Via token introspection endpoint, resource servers (`api.mydomain.com`) can check the validity of access tokens, and find out other information such as which user and which scopes are associated with the token.

For more information about token introspection refer to https://oauth.net/2/token-introspection/

This is the better but the harder solution, because you need to write a middleware or a guard authenticator in `api.mydomain.com` service to call introspection endpoint from `account.mydomain.com`

2) Share `oauth-private.key` and `oauth-public.key` in all your projects.

This is the easier way because the only thing you need to do is copying and pasting that two files from `storage` directory

Comment: But with the first option, the api service will be calling the account service for every request that comes to the api service

Comment: It's ok and is based on this rfc https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7662, the introspection api should be very lightweight.